# Laravel Extreme Eloquent - Select all where json

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a case where i have 3 tables

```
1) User's table
2) Roles Table
3) User_roles pivot table
```

In the pivot table besides the user_id and role_id i have an addition json field. This field has some json data which needs to be searched for.

Now lets say the json field has "foo" and "bar" in it, then i would like to search for all users where the user_roles pivot table's json field has foo inside it.

What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Is the JSON field a MySQL Text data type or MySQL native JSON type?

Comment: @kishanterry, Its a text datatype

Comment: If you want to query something, storing it in JSON format in a text type is probably the worst possible way.

Comment: hmmm ... I think you should have a look at this [Laracasts Video](https://laracasts.com/lessons/managing-mass-user-settings). Searching by where clause with `foo` and filtering the results in the code using `collection` pipelines (`map`, `filter`, `reduce`...) might also help. And yeah, as @ntzm pointed out, this might not be an efficient approach. Consider extracting another table out of the pivot if its not that complex.

Answer (score 1):

If you use MySQL 5.7 InnoDB or PostgreSQL 9.4, this should by good sollution https://www.sitepoint.com/use-json-data-fields-mysql-databases/